# XCode 3.2.6 hangs up

Tags: xcode

My Xcode 3.2.6 is hanging up constantly.
While I'm coding with no apparent reason it starts consuming more and more CPU, CPU temperature rises up to 80 celsius, the fan get exhausted and I'm forced to "force-quit" it and relaunch it to be able to continue working... 
It start happening this week and nobody else on my project is having the same troubles.
My OS is Snow leopard 10.6.8 
Any ideas on what could be happening?

Comment: I would move to Xcode4.2, which is available for both Lion and Snow Leopard. You're going to have to eventually. I found that Xcode3.2.6 didn't work quite right under Lion, and there could be something in 10.6.8, at some low level, that is also in Lion of course, that is contributing to your issue. This is total conjecture, but you never know. I've been using Xcode4.2 on Snow Leopard for quite a while with no issues, fwiw.

Comment: @MarkGranoff: those of us who still have to build for PowerPC can't move to Xcode 4.2 yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same exact issue with my Xcode 3.2.6 project...  Would start out using one core and if I let it sit, would use all 8 cores of my i7 MBP.  Very frustrating having to restart Xcode every 5 minutes.

My issue actually was resolved when I removed an iPhone from the Organizer that was running iOS 5.0.1.  Xcode was trying to get information from the iPhone, and wasn't able to, since the iOS SDK requires Xcode 4.x

I also removed all the user settings from within the project's *.xcodeproj package as well; not sure if that had additional effect.  removing those without removing the iPhone had no effect, though.

Comment: removed iphone from the organizer and it worked, thanks. How did you  find this out?

Comment: Honestly, it's been a while since I dealt with the issue, but if I remember correctly, my issue only happened when I had my phone plugged into my computer, so I just figured it was a compatibility issue between phone OS's and Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a "clean" on the target?  Have you tried checking your disk with Disk Utility?

Comment: Yes I've clean all targets & the disk is OK

Comment: How about trashing the com.apple.Xcode.plist prefs file, while Xcode is not running of course?

Comment: One more idea: open up the *.xcodeproj bundle, and delete the parts other than project.pbxproj.